# Persisting data for amazon ec2 instance running postgres

Tags: amazon-ec2, postgresql, terraform

I am provisioning a cheap postgres instance for myself by installing directly on amazon ec2.
Everything will be deployed using terraform.
I would like the database data to persist between restarts / teardown / redeploy of infra.

What is the conventional way to achieve this?

- **(a) define an amazon EBS resource separately**, so that terraform teardown does not destroy it, and always provide its arn as a mounted storage attachment to the ec2 instance?
- **(b) define amazon EBS resource with terraform**, but set a `final_snapshot = true` and also set a `snapshot_id` so that on *terraform destroy*, the data will be backed up somewhere. If so, how do I reincorporate this data in the next ec2 instance?
- **(c) something else** I don't know about / haven't thought of?

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provision the EBS resource out of band, fetch (or store) the volume id and associate with it. Or you can also use EFS the same way, using user-data to mount EFS on boot

Comment: Oh.. OK. I was literally about to try (b) when I saw this answer. Thanks for validating one approach. I think I'll go for EBS out of band then. But quick Q: can it not be attached via an `aws_volume_attachment` resource to auto-mount it? Is there a reason we would prefer to mount it via user data?

Comment: *UPDATE*: oh wait... i guess u suggested that because we won't have a `volume id` handy for creating an attachment, cos the volume was manually created. ok.